# need help querying dates in descending order in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

right now I created a function that works, it gets all the messages before the current time. But the thing is, it starts with the earliest messages first which is not what I want to do..

What would be the best work around or fix for this problem using sequelize?

```
module.exports.getMessages = function(chat_name, ammount, callback){
        Message.findAll({
            limit: ammount,
            where: {
                chat: chat_name,
                createdAt:{
                    $lt: new Date(),
                }
            }
        }).then(function(dates){
            return callback(null, dates)
        }).catch(function(err){
            return callback(err, null);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `order` property to object passed into `findAll`. `order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]`

```
module.exports.getMessages = function(chat_name, ammount, callback){
        Message.findAll({
            limit: ammount,
            where: {
                chat: chat_name,
                createdAt:{
                    $lt: new Date(),
                }
            },
            order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]
        }).then(function(dates){
            return callback(null, dates)
        }).catch(function(err){
            return callback(err, null);
        })
    }
```

More at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#ordering